# Problem with fetch and passing image through express

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express, fetch

I'm setting up a local nodejs server that can pass pictures I have locally through an express backend to my frontend.

I managed to get the picture to show up, but I find the solution a bit confusing and I am not sure if it's the optimal way to do it.

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/pics"));

app.get('/pic1', function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/pics/test.jpg");
});
```

This is a pretty straight forward endpoint to get the Picture to the frontend.

```
fetch("/pic1",{
})
    .then((response)=>{
        console.log(response);
    });
```

So I wanted to access the picture with fetch to display it but the response I get from fetch only gives me the url and no image to work with.

```
img.src = "/pic1";
```

If I skip using fetch completely and assign img the endpoint url, I get the actual image.

So my problem is I don't exactly understand why the second solution works and why I can't get the image through fetch. Is this even the best way to pass images to my frontend? I want to go down the express route so that eventually I could just adjust the endpoints if I ever get pictures that I don't have locally and is there a way I can stop an User from getting to the image by typing the url manually?. So maybe I am just not getting how the express endpoint works or how fetch works but this is where I am at.

Comment: when you assign the url of the image to the images src the browser will fetch it automatically. there is almost never any good reason to manually fetch an image. can you explain more about why you're trying to do that?

Comment: I actually just thought that would be the way to go, especially if I want to decide on how to display it.

Comment: fetching the image is going to give you raw binary data which you would then have to convert to a blob, which you would then have to convert to a datauri in order to display it anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's perfectly valid to set the url of the image directly rather than using fetch to pull it. The browser will then request the resource at /pic1 as the image in question (you'll see this in the network requests tab in developer tools)

If you wish to use fetch to pull image data you can try this code:

```
        console.log("Fetching image..");
        fetch("/pic1")
         .then(response => response.blob())
         .then(image => {
            let element = document.getElementById("testImg");
            element.setAttribute("src", URL.createObjectURL(image));
        });
```

This is assuming you have an img element like so:

```
<img id="testImg" />
```